# Can I pass additional classes to an Astro component from parent?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, astrojs

I'm working with an Astro component that already has some classes in its template. I'm looking to reuse this component in a different view to alter the color of its header exclusively for that view.

According to the documentation, passing a `class` prop makes adding classes from a parent to a child possible. However, I'm finding it challenging to retain the existing classes in the component while overriding or adding another class.

```html
<ExpansionQuestion question={question.question}>
  <Fragment slot="body" set:html={question.answer} />
</ExpansionQuestion>
```

`ExpansionQuestion` root element:

```html
<details class="group bg-blue-gray duration-300 rounded-lg p-4 w-full shadow-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-0">
```

My goal is to add a `bg-secondary` class to the `details` element in one specific view while ensuring the rest of the classes remain unchanged across all views.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One approach here is to use [Astro’s `class:list` directive](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#classlist). This lets you combine various classes more easily.

In your example, you might do something like this:

1. Pass the additional class to the component where you use it (here using a `bg` prop, but you could adapt this for whatever situation):

   ```
   <ExpansionQuestion question={question.question} bg="bg-secondary">
     <Fragment slot="body" set:html={question.answer} />
   </ExpansionQuestion>
   ```
2. Use the prop to control the background in the `ExpansionQuestion.astro` component:

   ```
   ---
   const { bg } = Astro.props;
   ---
   <details
     class:list={[
       "group duration-300 rounded-lg p-4 w-full",
       "shadow-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-0",
       bg || "bg-blue-gray"
     ]}
   >
   ```

   Astro will automatically combine the items in the `class:list` array, and in this case will use the `bg` prop if it is passed, but will default to the blue gray colour if no prop was passed.

Comment: Worked perfectly! I did notice the `class:list` directive, but I thought the list would get overwritten if I passed something to it; I didn't think of using a `prop` as a control for specific classes only

Answer (score 7):

Accept a `class` prop in the child component and apply it to the root element. You must rename it when destructuring because `class` is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#reserved_words) in JavaScript. Also, [this patch](https://github.com/withastro/docs/pull/4910) of the docs on Oct 13, 2023, highlighted that you should also use the rest parameter so that scoped styling works.

Child component:

```js
---
const { class: className, ...rest } = Astro.props
---

<div class:list={['child-component', className]} {...rest}>
  Child component
</div>

<style>
.child-component {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
</style>
```

Using it from parent:

```js
---
import ChildComponent from '...'
---

<div class="parent">
  <ChildComponent class="my-child-component"/>
</div>

<style>
.my-child-component {
  background: red;
}
</style>
```

More on that in [docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/styling/#passing-a-class-to-a-child-component)

Comment: This will not work because you are passing a scoped style. Astro uses the `data-astro-cid-*` attribute while applying styles, so you will need to get that id from parent, which you can do by using `...rest`.  It is mentioned in the docs link you provided.

Comment: Hmm it wasn't like that when I last used this. I checked the docs repo, what you mentioned was added [last week](https://github.com/withastro/docs/pull/4910) so now it should probably be used differently. At the time of writing my code worked, I have to update the answer.

Comment: I testet it, and it work. Also with the current version of Astro 3.4.0.

Comment: @AlexSedeke Probably because I already updated the answer, you can check the Edit History if you're curious about this

Comment: I think this is the right answer!